# Update Values of Multiple Array in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm updating an array and I wanted to update the `productCode` based on the given `newCode` response. This is by clicking the 'CREATE ALL PRODUCTS' button.
I'm thinking that the problem is on the reducer. It's currently not updating the `productCode` and `newProductCode`

Tip: `productIndex` is the key to finding it

Click Here: [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-autocomplete-productimages-hugo-forked-9lti4y?file=/src/reducers/productReducer.js)

**Action**

```
export const createAllProducts = (products) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: appConstants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST
    });

    const responses = [
      {
        config: null,
        data: {
          newCode: "NEW_AA"
        },
        headers: null
      },
      {
        config: null,
        data: {
          newCode: "NEW_FF"
        },
        headers: null
      },
      {
        config: null,
        data: {
          newCode: "NEW_GG"
        },
        headers: null
      }
    ];

    const finalResponses = responses.map((product, index) => ({
      newProductCode: product.data.newCode,
      productCode: product.data.newCode,
      productIndex: products[index].productIndex
    }));

    console.log(finalResponses);

    dispatch({
      type: appConstants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: finalResponses
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: appConstants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE
    });
  }
};
```

**Reducer**

```
case appConstants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
  const updatedProducts = state.products.map((product, index) => {
    const found = action.payload.find((el) => el.productIndex === index);

    return found
      ? {
          ...updatedProducts,
          productCode: found.productCode,
          newProductCode: found.newProductCode
        }
      : product;
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    isCreatingAllProducts: false,
    products: updatedProducts
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the reducer

```
case appConstants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((product, index) => {
      const found = action.payload.find((el) => el.productIndex === index);
      console.log(found);

      return found
        ? {
            ...product,
            productCode: found.productCode,
            newProductCode: found.newProductCode
          }
        : product;
    })
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You used *reduce* methods with the initial value state, which is the actually old state.
Consider this example:

```js
const state = { history: null }
const payload = [ 'hello', 'equal' ]

//your current reducer
const newState = payload.reduce((acc, cur) => { acc[cur] = cur; return acc } , state)


//the state reference point to the same obj, then redux will not trigger re-render
console.log(newState === state) // true
```